# Processes not terminating

Tags: c, tcp

There are some strange things happening in my client-server application. Please, look at these simple fork client/server:
CLIENT:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


#define IP_SERVER "192.168.1.89"
#define PORT_SERVER 65000
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
#define NUMFILES 3


double timeElapsed(struct timeval* before, struct timeval* after) {

  return after->tv_sec - before->tv_sec + (double) (after->tv_usec - before->tv_usec)/1000000;
}


void getFile(char *request, struct sockaddr_in server) {

  char buffer[1024];
  int sockProc, res;
  int file;
  int sizeServ = sizeof(server);
  int writeFile;

  sockProc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (sockProc < 0) {
      printf("Error on creating socket client\n");
      perror("");
      exit(1);
  }

  file = open(request, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU);


  res = connect(sockProc, (struct sockaddr*)&server, (socklen_t)sizeServ);
  if (res < 0) {
      printf("Error on connecting to server!\n");
      perror("");
      exit(1);
  }

  res = send(sockProc, (void*)request, strlen(request), 0);

  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

  while((res = recv(sockProc, (void*)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0) {
      write(file, (void*)buffer, strlen(buffer));
      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  }


  close(sockProc);
  close(file);
  return;

  }


  int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int sockCli, res, i;

  struct sockaddr_in server;
  int sizeServ = sizeof(server);
  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_pton(AF_INET, IP_SERVER, &server.sin_addr);
  server.sin_port = htons(PORT_SERVER);

  char files[NUMFILES][32];
  char nameFile[32];

  char command[32] = "rm *.txt";

  system(command);

  struct timeval begin;
  struct timeval end;

  pid_t processes[NUMFILES];



  for(i = 0; i<NUMFILES; i++) {

      memset(nameFile, 0, sizeof(nameFile));
      printf("Inserisci nome file (con estensione) da ricevere:\n");
      scanf("%s", nameFile);
      strcpy(files[i], nameFile);

  }


  gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);

  for(i=0; i<NUMFILES; i++) {

      pid_t child = fork();

      if(child == 0) {
          getFile(files[i], server);
          exit(0);
      }

      else {
          processes[i] = child;
          continue;
      }

  }


  /*for(i=0; i<NUMFILES; i++) {
      waitpid(processes[i], NULL, 0);
  }*/

  wait(NULL);

  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
  printf("Time elapsed on TCP is %f seconds\n", timeElapsed(&begin, &end));
  return 0;

  }
```

and the SERVER:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define IP_SERVER "192.168.1.89"
#define PORT_SERVER 65000
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

void execRequest(int* sockCli, struct sockaddr_in* client) {

  char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
  char request[BUFFERSIZE];
  int res;

  memset(request, 0, sizeof(request));

  res = recv(*sockCli, (void*)request, sizeof(request), 0);

  if(res < 0) {
      printf("Error on recv()\n");
      perror("");
      exit(1);
  }
  printf("Requested file %s\n", request);

  char resource[32] = "files/";
  strcat(resource, request);

  int file = open(resource, O_RDONLY);

  if (file < 0) {
      printf("File %s does not exist\n", request);
      exit(1);
  }

  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

  while((res = read(file, (void*)buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
      send(*sockCli, (void*)buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  }

  close((*sockCli));
  close(file);
  free(sockCli);
  free(client);

  return;

  }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int sockServ, i, res;
  int *sockCli;

  struct sockaddr_in server;
  struct sockaddr_in* client;


  sockServ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if(sockServ < 0) {
      printf("Error in creating socket\n");
      perror("");
      exit(1);
  }

  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_SERVER);
  server.sin_port = htons(PORT_SERVER);
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;

  int reuse = 1;
  res = setsockopt(sockServ, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(int));
  if (res < 0) {
      printf("setsockopt() REUSEADDR failed\n");
      perror("");
      exit(1);
  }

  res = bind(sockServ, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
  if (res < 0) {
      printf("Error on bindind TCP server!\n");
      perror("");
      exit(1);
  }

  res = listen(sockServ, 5);
  if (res < 0) {
      printf("Error on listening TCP server!\n");
      perror("");
      exit(1);
  }

  while(1) {

      sockCli = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
      client = (struct sockaddr_in*)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
      int sizeClient = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

      *sockCli = accept(sockServ, (struct sockaddr*)client, &sizeClient);

      if ((*sockCli) < 0) {
                printf("accept() failed\n");
        perror("");
        continue;
      }

      printf("Connected to %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client->sin_addr), client->sin_port);

      if( !fork() ) {

          execRequest(sockCli, client);
          exit(0);

      }

      else
          continue;



}

  return 0;


  }
```

This is very strange. The processes created by the client don't terminate even if the server closes the sockets and so recv() should return 0 and let client processes exit from the loop. Moreover there's something strange about reading files:
the server simply reads files.txt but in doing this it includes the string ".txt" in the read characters and sends all this mixture to the client...why?
they are simple file mono character like
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

but the server reads and and sends:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

can I solve all this?

Comment: Did you use a debugger like `gdb` on Linux? Did you compile with all warnings & debug info, i.e. with `gcc -Wall -g`  ?

Comment: If you want us to read your code, please make it readable... Consistent whitespace/tabbing would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `strlen(buffer)`, just because you're loading characters from a text file doesn't mean that `buffer` will be a valid string unless you take steps to ensure it is. And you don't; there's no termination since you can fill all of `buffer` with data from the file.

Comment: the problem I see is that if the server is monoprocess everything finishes...instead using fork() to create process it doesn't...what's the difference?

Comment: what unwind says is not correct. reading from file stops when there's nothing more to read, even if the buffer is not completely filled. in fact the server process closes connection but it semms that the client process does not see it...

Answer (score 0):

How many times must we play the broken record here on Stack Overflow? [Don't cast malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)!

I chalk this error to *failure to read the manual(s)*, to find out *what header to include*, *what a string is* (and hence what strlen/strcat/str*{anything}* expects of its input, what printf expects of arguments that correspond to a `%s` format specifier, etc.) and *what read/recv produces*.

```
res = recv(*sockCli, (void*)request, sizeof(request), 0);
if(res < 0) {
    printf("Error on recv()\n");
    perror("");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Requested file %.*s\n", res, request); // NOTE the field width provided by 'res'
```

By the manual, examples such as `res = read(file, (void*)buffer, sizeof(buffer))` supposedly store either an error or a length. The condition ensures that the `send` code will only execute when it's a *length* value, so why not use it as one? `send(*sockCli, (void*)buffer, res, 0);`?

The presense of these problems seems to indicate that your method of learning isn't working. Which book are you reading? Learning C without a book is a bit like learning which berries are poisonous without communication.

Comment: well, something I solved, thanks to what you've said...now I use res in the send() call and files received don't have that ".txt" anymore...but still the client doesn't stop. I don't undertstand why that damned recv() in the client processes dosn't return 0 when the socket is closed! :(+

Comment: ps: I think I know C...I wrote 3 projects in C, even a simple kernel unix as the operating system project. But I think that I'm forgetting how to use some system calls...

Comment: @user2204592 Well, you've demonstrated the inability to read and comprehend the manual. You've demonstrated the inability to read and comprehend my questions. Is this a reading disability, or a comprehension disability? If it's a reading disability, perhaps you could use whatever mechanism you use on stackoverflow to transform the manual to something you can comprehend. If it's a comprehension disability, you *really shouldn't* be a programmer...

Comment: @user2204592 Which standards does your Unix kernel comply to?

Comment: please I don't want to talk about my past projects now...I don't think I'm a good programmer, I'm not that proud. I think I'm still learning...I'm still a student dear, not a worker. Now please...I really would know...why that damned client processes don't finish! WHY?

Comment: @user2204592: Please take time to learn how to use the `gdb` debugger. It is a skill useful for every *C* or *C++* programmer (at least on Unix systems). Then, use `gdb` twice (e.g. in two different terminals, or inside `emacs`): once to run the server, and once to run the client....

Comment: @user2204592 The more significant problem is that you don't appear to be the *manual reading* type. How can you be sure your kernel was in fact a Unix kernel if you don't know which standard compliance is required of a Unix kernel? Why is your client process not finishing? Why haven't you fixed your source code indentation yet? Those three answers are highly likely to correspond at some point involving *reading*.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That would be helpful advice, but this person probably won't *read and/or comprehend it*. I requested that he/she indent his code correctly to encourage us to read it, rather than use it as toilet paper, earlier. No effort was made to indent the code. The user has suggested that his/her code has changed. Without knowing those changes, how are we supposed to accurately diagnose the problem? It seems like the answer to "Which book are you reading?" should be "Crystal Clear Communication"...

Comment: I did what you asked...sorry for the late, I'm full of work in this moment. Here 's how I solved the problem...it was the first time I had used fork() in a network area and so I didn't know exactely how to do it...I leave my code. the lines with /*************+/ were the most critical to me:

Comment: after having performed fork(), the child server process must close the listening socket. Then it can recv() from client. Instead parent process, before starting again at loop while(1), must first close the socket "accepted"...that was all. 

I know I'm not a good computer science student but now I've made my choice and I'll finish it. There is no need to be some ACIDIC and ARROGANT like you!

Comment: @user2204592 In order to justify calling me arrogant, you'd need to point out where I "reveal an exaggerated sense of my own importance or abilities". This would be difficult, since most of the time I've been talking about *you*. Do you think you're *too good to have to read*? It is a significant part of a programmer's job to read. If you don't, you won't last long! That's blunt honesty, not arrogance. Don't confuse them. Now, please *read* everything I've said and follow the suggestions that they imply (eg. *update your code*), unless you are that important that I must repeat myself.

Comment: Ohh, heck. I'll repeat myself. Please fix these and provide us with an update of your code: `strcat(resource, request);` ... `printf("Requested file %s\n", request);` ... `strlen(request)` ... `strlen(buffer)`. It's reasonable to expect a program to crash/hang on any of these (or cause earthquakes), since they're all instances of undefined behaviour. Please remove any casts too/from `void *` (which includes `malloc` casts). If any compiler warnings or errors pop up, let us know. Otherwise, check if the symptoms are still there.